# XSLT : How to assign a value to global variable

Tags: xml, xslt

Just I want to do simple addition. When i iterate values, just i want to do sum and print that value.

This is the way which i tried. But it is just printing 0.

This is my xml.

```
        <t:Employee>
        <t:Earnings_Deductions>
            <t:Amount t:PriorValue="">4000</t:Amount>
        </t:Earnings_Deductions>
        </t:Employee>
        <t:Employee>
        <t:Earnings_Deductions>
            <t:Amount t:PriorValue="">4000</t:Amount>
        </t:Earnings_Deductions>
        </t:Employee>
        <t:Employee>
        <t:Earnings_Deductions>
            <t:Amount t:PriorValue="">4000</t:Amount>
        </t:Earnings_Deductions>
        </t:Employee>
```

I want to add all the Amount and show it like this.

```
<item><p>700000</p></item>

<xsl:variable name="Total_Amount" select="0" />
        <item>

        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name() = 'Employee']">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name() = 'Earning_Deductions']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="amount"><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name() = 'Amount']"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Total_Amount"><xsl:value-of select="$Total_Amount + $amount"/></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="$Total_Amount"></xsl:value-of></p>
        </item>
```

I am new to xslt. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: That's not how XSLT works - variables cannot be updated. Show [a complete input XML sample, a complete XSLT stylesheet and the output you expect](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - I'm sure there is another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT variables are immutable. Once they are set, they cannot be changed.

Using the [`sum()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-sum) function, you can produce the total amount without looping constructs or the need to change the variable value:

```
<xsl:variable name="Total_Amount" 
     select="sum(//*[local-name()='Employee']/*[local-name()='Earning_Deductions']/*[local-name()='Amount'])"/> 
<xsl:value-of select="$Total_Amount"/>
```

Comment: I want to add all the Amount. Where should i mention it?

Comment: Sorry, I had it adding the `Earning_Deductions` instead of the `Amount`. I have updated the XPath expression.